# DRC Robot Head meshes are missing when loading robot at drcsim v1.2

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Title is self-explanatory but when I load DRC robot model a few head meshes are missing.

Regards,

LR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/533/drc-robot-head-meshes-are-missing-when-loading-robot-at-drcsim-v1.2/) by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[drc robot model in drcsim 1.2](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/d622ff0b978c67615973de99c6d8e5ae6719699a/models/drc_robot/model.urdf?at=drcsim_1.2#cl-22) refers to [multisense_sl model meshes](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/d622ff0b978c67615973de99c6d8e5ae6719699a/models/multisense_sl/meshes?at=drcsim_1.2).  Check if your installed files includes `/usr/share/drcim-1.2/models/multisense_sl/meshes/base_link.STL` and `/usr/share/drcim-1.2/models/multisense_sl/meshes/hokuyo_link.STL` as shown in the bitbucket link.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0